# C++ declare a string array with content and size based on user input

Tags: c++, xcode, dynamic

I am trying to set up an array of string that's size and content dependent on the users input.  I am getting an error declaring my array, it says the variable for the size is not the right type.  I've spent a few hours on this just thought I'd ask.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter number of names /n";
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    string namesArray[a];         //Error is here.
    for( int i=0; i<a; i++) {
        string temp;
        cin >> temp;
        namesArray[i] = temp;
    }

    for( int j=0; j<a; j++) {
        cout << "hello " << namesArray[j] << "/n";

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The error is at `string namesArray[a];`

Comment: Variables can't be used as array sizes, you have to use a compile-time constant. What you want is `std::vector`, a runtime-resizable array class.

Comment: Please post the EXACT error you are getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array needs to have a compile-time value for its size. Your code wont compile because `a` is not a compile-time constant.

Better use `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>   // <-- Must be included

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout << "Enter number of names /n";
    int a;
    cin >> a;

    vector<string> namesArray;    // HERE!!!

    for( int i=0; i < a; i++) {
        string temp;
        cin >> temp;
        namesArray.push_back(temp);   // Notice the difference
    }

    for( int j=0; j<a; j++) {
        cout << "hello " << namesArray[j] << "/n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how dow i use? new import?

Comment: @user1807880 Just edited.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare your namesArray in this way:

```
string * namesArray = new string[a];
```

This should work, since it dynamically allocates memory based on input value a.

But certainly, it is better to use vector instead. You don't need to delete the array if use vector.

Comment: However, you need to be careful to ensure that it never goes out of scope to prevent a memory leak. Since it's in main though, this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a variable as the size of statically intiailised array, to do this you need to dynamically allocate your array, with something like

```
string* namesArray =  new string[a];
```

But it is much wiser to use std::vector instead and save yourself from memory leaks!

With a vector you can do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter number of names /n";
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    vector<string> names;
    for( int i=0; i<a; i++) {
        string temp;
        cin >> temp;
        names.push_back(temp);
    }

    vector<string>::iterator
        it = names.begin(),
        ite = names.end();
    for(; it != ite; ++it) {
        cout << "hello " << *it << "/n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Mark said, it's a compile-time issue. You can use `vector`, but another way to do this would be to dynamically allocate memory for the array. This would mean using the keyword `new`.

So, your code would be `string* namesArray = new string[a];`

Using `new` returns a pointer to the array, so adjust accordingly.